# Setting degree of polynomial for SVM

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm, polynomials

I am training an SVM in Matlab and would like to set the kernel to a polynomial with degree of 2.

How can I write the code to achieve this?

```
%# train one-against-all models
model = cell(numLabels,1);
for k=1:numLabels
    model{k} = svmtrain(double(trainLabel==k), trainData, '-s 0 -t 1 -d 2 -g 1 -b 1 ');
end

%# get probability estimates of test instances using each model
prob = zeros(numTest,numLabels);
for k=1:numLabels
    [~,~,p] = svmpredict(double(testLabel==k), testData, model{k}, '-b 1');
    prob(:,k) = p(:,model{k}.Label==1);    %# probability of class==k
end

%# predict the class with the highest probability
[~,pred] = max(prob,[],2);
acc = sum(pred == testLabel) ./ numel(testLabel) %# accuracy
C = confusionmat(testLabel, pred);               %# confusion matrix
```

Comment: http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html suggests `PolynomialOrder` or `polyOrder`.

Comment: hey jbaums, how to write the code if i want write in options way ? for example using the -d 2 -t 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Matlab. I suggest you add some more detail to your question. Show us your current code (the relevant parts), and what you've tried.

Comment: okay :) thanks you ...  i am trying to test the accurate for my makeup face recognition using svm kernel type polynomial degree 2 , but i facing the coding problem to set the polynomial degree 2 ..

Comment: Are you sure you haven't already specified a degree of 2? The docs for `libsvm` suggest the flag is `-d`: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

Comment: hmm~ i think it have been set already but not yet reach the expectation and i think maybe my code having problem. now, trying the other way .. thanks :)